# How to set the color of a horizontal line in Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

How can I set the color of a `horizontal_line` in [Prawn PDF](http://prawnpdf.org)?

This is what I've got:

```
horizontal_line 0, 540, :at => line
```

It seems this is nowhere documented in the [manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly you can use stroke_color to set the color on a line like:

```
    mypdf.stroke_color "f0ffc1"
```

or

```
    mypdf.stroke_color 0,0,0,0 // for CMYK
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That works! Strange, I thought that I had tried that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To draw a grey horizontal line you must use `stroke_horizontal_rule`.

This works:

```
pdf.stroke_color 'dddddd'
pdf.stroke_horizontal_rule
```